# Only trigger Jenkinsfile build for changes to certain paths

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile for several multibranch pipelines in the same repository, and one thing I find frustrating is that all pipelines are triggered when I make any change, when often in reality only one pipeline actually needs to be triggered.

Is it possible, using a Jenkins file, to selectively include or exclude paths that will result in a build being triggered?

I'm thinking of something similar to below, but looking at [the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) I cannot see any reference to such a simple way of doing this. However, I'm new to Jenkins so I'm hoping that I'm missing something.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'Codebuild'
    }
    trigger {
        include '/some/path
    }
    stages {
        stage('Do the magic') {
            steps {
                script {
                    ...do stuff here...
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `when condition`to determine whether the stage should be executed depending on the given condition.
In this can you can use  the option/condition `changeset` to limit stage execution only to the case when specific files are changed.

For more info about `when` and `changeset` option :
 https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Example:

```
stages {
    stage('Do the magic') {
       // Below condition you can change based on your usecase
        when { changeset "src/*.js"}
        steps {
            sh "make build"
            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately this will still result in the pipeline being triggered, which is an undesirable outcome, but it's better than having builds running when they don't need to.

Comment: @DavidGard correct trigger would happen but nothing will be executed